# What's the difference between Kotlin/Native and Java bytecode with compile through LLVM frontend?

Tags: java, kotlin, llvm, kotlin-native

Kotlin have great technology for compiling to native binaries - it's based on LLVM.
But Java bytecode can compile to LLVM too - there is a [java frontend](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/java/trunk/docs/java-frontend.txt) for compile .class files into LLVM bitcode.
What differences, if I compile Kotlin through Kotlin Native or if I compile Kotlin to Java bytecode, and then compile bytecode to LLVM bitcode?

Comment: That frontend is far from being a finished, usable compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: there is no java frontend :) It was basically something proof-of-concept which never went out of experimental state.

Comment: Anton: never say never ;)